# nginx: [emerg] "index" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

I tried
`nginx -t`  and everything seems right.

I get this error:

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz -T
nginx: [emerg] "index" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz test failed
```

My config file is this:

```
index   index.html index.htm;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name premonstrati2021.cz;

        #port_in_redirect off;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

#       if ($scheme != "https") {
#               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#       }
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;

        root /var/www/html/app/dist;

        server_name  premonstrati2021.cz www.premonstrati2021.cz;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem
        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/privkey.pem";
        ssl_verify_client      optional;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE$

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/premonstrati.access.log  main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/log/premonstrati.com.br.error.log;

        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000/api;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;

                proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

       location /widget {
               root /var/www/html/app/widget;

               if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                }
       }
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.premonstrati2021.cz;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I can't restart nginx because there is error but I am not able to find any mistake. I just added block with location /widget { ... } . I tried to delete it but without success. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question. Notice the capital `-T`.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I edited my question - you can see it now. I think it is ok there is include `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Comment: My target was to change root for url /widget/ because I want to have there CORS content. But it doesn't work.

Comment: But you haven't enabled this site!

Answer (score 2):

The directive `index index.html index.htm;` should go inside `server {}` context, but you have it outside any `server`.

Move it to appropriate context, e.g.:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name premonstrati2021.cz;

        index   index.html index.htm;

        #port_in_redirect off;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

#       if ($scheme != "https") {
#               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#       }
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;

        root /var/www/html/app/dist;

        server_name  premonstrati2021.cz www.premonstrati2021.cz;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem
        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/privkey.pem";
        ssl_verify_client      optional;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE$

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/premonstrati.access.log  main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/log/premonstrati.com.br.error.log;

        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000/api;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;

                proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

       location /widget {
               root /var/www/html/app/widget;

               if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                }
       }
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.premonstrati2021.cz;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now there is 


nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz test failed

Comment: When you run a check like this: `nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz -T`, you're specifying that `/etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz` is the complete configuration for NGINX to use. But it is incomplete, because `server` must go within `http {}` context. Test it as simply `nginx -t` or specify the main `nginx.conf` for testing.

Comment: when I use `nginx -t` I get `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`. 

It is strange because when I try to delete part of my config upper - for example  ``location /api {...}`` and restart, it still works, so it seems that it is without change.

Comment: does ``nginx -t`` test also included files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a symlink from file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/premonstrati2021.cz` in order to nginx actually to use your configuration.

At the moment, your configuration is in a file under `sites-available`, but nginx does not include files from there.

Also, this block is wrong:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.premonstrati2021.cz;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This creates an infinite 301 redirect loop. Since there already is a `server` block for `www.premonstrati2021.cz`, you should simply delete this block.

Comment: Probably you have truth but I cannot understand how is it possible that my config worked before :-/

I tried to add include sites-available/ after `nginx -T` I have I have this error `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~#" in /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz.save:27
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Please don't add includes to `sites-available`. Create a symlink like I wrote. The error you are seeing is because you have extra files in `sites-available`.

Comment: OK, but I don't know how. I am sorry am new to nginx.

Comment: I tried this `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/premonstrati2021.cz /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/premonstrati2021.cz`. And now there is error `nginx: [emerg] no ssl_client_certificate for ssl_client_verify
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` ... I have to say that my website worked fine (with SSL, redirect to HTTPS).

Comment: Finally `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` but now `Aug 07 13:25:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 nginx[8598]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
 ...` I tried kill TCP on port 80 but without success.

Comment: On that port I had my node app. Stopped it, started nginx (without starting my node app in PM2)  and it work, I absolutely dont understand how, but it still works. It is strange

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ouch

Comment: You need to make your app listen on port 3000.

Comment: Config looks well. Web runs on port 80. `curl https://premonstrati2021.cz
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
` I edited my conf uppper

Comment: now I can get curl response on https on server. but I cant see website in browser. :-/